Caplin flexlayout-react drag drop onto border bar?
I have a working Border bar implementation, but I'd like to be able to have a popout window that can be dragged onto of the border bar, then also popped back out. Is that possible ? It seems like the border bar is more static than the other tab configurations. I don't want any other tab sets, just border bar.
